# Pre-processing Emulator for JavaScript ( Timing / Debug Example )

Tags: javascript, c++

In C++ you can omit compiling debug code by using pre-processing directives in order to keep your compiled code fast and not hindered by debug code not needed in production.

Is there a correlative way to do this in JavaScript?  What I have been doing in the past is commenting out debug code, but I want a cleaner way to do it.

An example below shows 4 if statements that activate if debug is set to true.  However in production I don't want this checked 4 times when I know it will be set to false.  As I mentioned I could cram it into one line and comment it out...but I want a clean way to do it?

```
/**
 **  cType
 */

function cType( o_p ) {
    if( debug ) {
        var t1, t2, t3, t4, i1, i2, i3; t1 = new Date().getTime();
    }
    o_p = MType[ o_p.model ].pre( o_p ); 
    if ( o_p.result !== 'complete' ) {
        if( debug ) {
            t2 = new Date().getTime();
            console.log( '---------------Send to Server - object_pipe: \n ' + o_p.toSource() ); 
        } 
        var string_pipe = JSON.stringify( o_p );
        cMachine( 'pipe=' + string_pipe , function( string_pipe ) {
            if( debug ) { 
                console.log( '---------------Receive from Server - object_pipe: \n ' + string_pipe ); 
                t3 = new Date().getTime();
            }
            MType[ o_p.model ].post( JSON.parse( string_pipe ) );
            if( debug ) {
                t4 = new Date().getTime(); i1 = t2-t1 ; i2 = t3-t2 ; i3 = t4-t3;
                console.log( '---------------Pre, Transit, Post = ', i1, i2, i3 );  
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really because you don't have compiled code. But you could use some tool that makes those conditions `if(false)` on production. Smart interpreters will remove it right away when parsing.

Comment: What do you mean by smart interpreter?...Is there a way to look at what optimizations a smart interpreter makes?

Comment: Modern browsers, for example. They may optimize away such cases.

Comment: Do you know of a way to look at the optimizations....in C++ you can look at the assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pass it through c preprocessor like:

```
gcc -E input.js -o output.js
```

This will allow you to use #if and even include and macros.

Comment: this is a good use of gcc... I can use this to easily write dynamic code for css and html as well...then create static files at build time.

Comment: If that's really the way you want to develop Javascript code I think you should use CoffeeScript

Comment: IMHO, you're better off using tools that are language-aware. That would give you the most freedom while making your code look less ugly.  For CSS, look at http://lesscss.org/.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org), you can use [build pragmas](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) and even the [has.js integration](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#hasjs) to disable/enable code fragments at optimization (minification) time.

Comment: It doesn't do it at a "preprocessor" level. It's actually JavaScript-aware. It relies on UglifyJS which actually parses your code and prunes dead branches. It's pretty smart...

Comment: How does it remove the excess code?...it has to modify the source some how?

Comment: This happens during minification. Your code is already passed through parsing + reconstitution during the process.

Answer (score 0):

No, Javascript is not compiled, it's interpreted. Therefore it's impossible to have preprocessing directives unless you pass non-standard Javascript - it probably won't be Javascript anymore - code through another utility.

Comment: you can emulate it using a build tool...that's why I said emulate.